# My Eclipse IDE does not have the menu to install the emulator of Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to install Android development tools bundle inside my Eclipse Indigo. I installed the bundle. The problem is that I cannot see any menu inside Eclipse to create the virtual device. Some documentation said that it is in Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager , but my Window menu does not contain it ! So how to install the emulator inside Eclipse Indigo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) on how to do that.

Comment: Ok , the reason why I didnt see the emulator manager is that I use the wronge Eclipse IDE ! Now I use the one provided in the eclipse folder of the bundle and it works !